# how to make cohort analysis in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `order_star_member`:

```sql
create table order_star_member(
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   users_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
   createdAt datetime NOT NULL,
   total_price_star_member decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO order_star_member(users_id, createdAt, total_price_star_member)
VALUES
(15, '2021-01-01', 350000),
(15, '2021-01-02', 400000),
(16, '2021-01-02', 700000),
(15, '2021-02-01', 350000),
(16, '2021-02-02', 700000),
(15, '2021-03-01', 350000),
(16, '2021-03-01', 850000),
(17, '2021-03-03', 350000);
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5d0d18326b6fd2ad027a6c064dd24a4e)

I want to find users in the month March with `transaction >= 700000` and  `first transaction >= 700000`. The user whose transaction is `>= 700000` is called `star member`.

My query so far:

```sql
    SELECT COUNT(users_id) count_star_member,
           year_and_month DIV 100 `year`,
           year_and_month MOD 100 `month`
    FROM (SELECT users_id, 
                 MIN(year_and_month) year_and_month
          FROM ( SELECT users_id, 
                        DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') year_and_month,
                        SUM(total_price_star_member) month_price
                 FROM order_star_member
                 GROUP BY users_id, 
                          DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') 
                 HAVING month_price >= 350000 ) starrings
          GROUP BY users_id
          HAVING SUM(year_and_month = '202103') > 0 ) first_starrings
    GROUP BY year_and_month
    ORDER BY `year`, `month`;

    +-------------------+------+-------+
    | count_star_member | year | month |
    +-------------------+------+-------+
    |                 1 | 2021 |     1 |
    +-------------------+------+-------+
```

Explanation: in march 2021, there's only one 'star member', which is `users_id 16`, whose first transaction is in `january 2021`, so 'star member' in march 2021 is as above.

But starting from March, the definition of 'star member' changes from 700,000 to 350,000.

I want to find the 'star member' in March, and his first transaction, but if the first transaction is in a month before March 2021, then the star member should be the user whose transaction >= 700,000 -- but if the first transaction is in March 2021, as I sid, select a user whose transaction >= 350,000.

Thus my updated expectation:

```
        +-------------------+------+-------+
        | count_star_member | year | month |
        +-------------------+------+-------+
        |                 2 | 2021 |     1 |
        |                 1 | 2021 |     3 |
        +-------------------+------+-------+
```

Explanation : users 15, 16, and 17 are star member in march 2021. but users 15 and 16 are doing their first star member in January 2021 (because it is before March 2021, when the requirement to become star member is 700,000), while user 17 is also a star member because the first transaction is 350,000 in March 2021.

Comment: no, it isn't. please check my fiddle

Comment: Please formulate the final form of the task, its history isn't interesting for us. And specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina in the fiddle he is using `5.7.33`.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara There is no free version selection in the fiddle. And it is possible that real server version does not matched to one selected in a fiddle - so explicit version specifying may be useful.

Comment: im using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that in determining the final output, you need 2 things:

1. A user's first transaction
2. The users who are star members for the requested month using the condition that before March 2021 cumulative monthly transaction amounts >=700000 and after March >=350000

If correct, since you are using a version less than 8.0(where it could be done with one statement) your solution is as follows:

1. You need a rules table or some configuration of rules (we'll call it SMLimitDef) which would look like this entered directly in a table:

```
insert into SMLimitDef(sEffDate,eEffDate,priceLimit) 
VALUES('1980-01-01','2021-02-28',700000),
('2021-03-01','2999-12-31',350000);
```

2. Next, you need a query or view that figures out your first transactions(called vFirstUserTransMatch) which would look something like this:

```
create view vFirstUserTransMatch as
SELECT *,month(osm.createdAt) as createMonth, year(osm.createdAt) as createYear 
FROM order_star_member osm
where createdAt=(select MIN(createdAt) from order_star_member b 
                  where b.users_id=osm.users_id
                 )
```

3. Next you need a summary view or query that summarizes transactions per month per user

```
create view vOSMSummary as
SELECT users_id,month(osm.createdAt) as createMonth, year(osm.createdAt) as createYear, sum(total_price_star_member) as totalPrice 
FROM order_star_member osm
group by users_id,month(osm.createdAt), year(osm.createdAt);
```

4. Next you need a query that puts it all together based on your criteria:

```
select osm.*,futm.createMonth as firstMonth, futm.createYear as firstYear 
from vOSMSummary osm 
inner join vFirstUserTransMatch futm
on osm.users_id=futm.users_id
where exists(select 'x' from SMLimitDef c 
             where osm.createMonth between Month(c.sEffDate) and Month(c.eEffDate)
             and osm.createYear between Year(c.sEffDate) and Year(c.eEffDate)
             and osm.totalPrice>=c.pricelimit
            )
and osm.CreateMonth=3 and osm.createYear=2021
```

5. Lastly, you can do your summary

```
SELECT COUNT(users_id) count_star_member,
       firstYear `year`,
       firstMonth `month`
FROM (
select osm.*,futm.createMonth as firstMonth, futm.createYear as firstYear 
from vOSMSummary osm 
inner join vFirstUserTransMatch futm
on osm.users_id=futm.users_id
where exists(select 'x' from SMLimitDef c 
             where osm.createMonth between Month(c.sEffDate) and Month(c.eEffDate)
             and osm.createYear between Year(c.sEffDate) and Year(c.eEffDate)
             and osm.totalPrice>=c.pricelimit
            )
and osm.CreateMonth=3 and osm.createYear=2021
) d
group by firstYear, firstMonth
```

Like I said, if you were using mySQL 8, everything could be in one query using "With" statements but for your version, for readability and simplicity, you need views otherwise you can still embed the sql for those views into the final sql.

Fiddle looks like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0084e0174a2aebdb6493af5cf1940027)

Contrast with version 8 which looks like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ec94c9ad4d932b09922812b86371faf)

Comment: THIS IS SUPERB, so far so good, i was just wondering, so basically  ```SMLimitDef``` table is used to make a condition based on mine? (Regarding with transaction in ```700000``` and ```350000```

Comment: when i was change it from ```and month(osm.createdAt)=3 and year(osm.createdAt)=2021``` into ```and month(osm.createdAt)=1 and year(osm.createdAt)=2021``` why the count user_id is just 1, instead it should be 2, because both users_id 15 and 16 are doing his first transaction in january 2021 and has transaction >= 700000. please check my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2f5bda61802a3b9f02d463f1985ca225

Comment: i think its because this query just looks for just 1 transaction in 1 user, instead, it should be looking at the total transaction for each user in each month. so it only consider users_id 16 as a star member because the transaction directly in ```700000``` while users_id 15 has 2 transactions in ```350000``` and ```400000```

Comment: Yes SMLimitDef is for your condition.

Comment: Ok so star membership is cumulative for the month. Makes sense. I'll modify to fit

Comment: Made the change and all I added was a view of the summary of the source table to use in the final statements instead of the source table itself.

Comment: oh my god i missclick about the bounty :(

Comment: im feeling sad, im sorry

Comment: sir im really really sorry, oh mygodness

Comment: :) no worries. Glad you got your answer. That's what counts.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you need:

```
SELECT min_year, min_month, COUNT(users_id)
FROM (
    SELECT osm2.users_id, YEAR(min_createdAt) min_year, MONTH(min_createdAt) min_month, SUM(total_price_star_member) sum_price
    FROM (
        SELECT users_id, MIN(createdAt) min_createdAt       
        FROM order_star_member
        GROUP BY users_id
    ) AS osm1
    JOIN order_star_member osm2 ON osm1.users_id = osm2.users_id
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(osm2.createdAt, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(osm1.min_createdAt, '%Y%m')
    GROUP BY osm2.users_id, min_createdAt
) t1
WHERE users_id IN (
    SELECT users_id
    FROM (
        SELECT users_id, DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y-%m-01') month_createdAt
        FROM order_star_member
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') = '202103'
        GROUP BY users_id, DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y-%m-01')
        HAVING SUM(total_price_star_member) >= (
            CASE
                WHEN date(month_createdAt) < date '2021-03-01' THEN 700000
                ELSE 350000
            END
        )
    ) t3
) AND       
    (((min_year < 2021 OR min_month < 3) AND t1.sum_price >= 700000) OR 
    ((min_year = 2021 AND min_month = 3) AND t1.sum_price >= 350000))
GROUP BY min_year, min_month
```

First you find the `MIN(createdAt)` for each member, with:

```
SELECT users_id, MIN(createdAt) min_createdAt       
FROM order_star_member
GROUP BY users_id
```

Then you compute the `SUM` of all the `total_price_star_member` in the month of the `min_createdAt` date:

```
SELECT osm2.users_id, YEAR(min_createdAt) min_year, MONTH(min_createdAt) min_month, SUM(total_price_star_member) sum_price
FROM osm1
JOIN order_star_member osm2 ON osm1.users_id = osm2.users_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(osm2.createdAt, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(osm1.min_createdAt, '%Y%m')
GROUP BY osm2.users_id, min_createdAt
```

Next you filter on the month you are interested in. Here you cannot use `HAVING` with something that cannot be computed from what you have in the `GROUP BY` statement, so you need to project also `DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y-%m-01')` to establish the minimum total price for star membership in the `HAVING` clause that is now allowed.

```
SELECT users_id
FROM (
    SELECT users_id, DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y-%m-01') month_createdAt
    FROM order_star_member
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') = '202102'
    GROUP BY users_id, DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y-%m-01')
    HAVING SUM(total_price_star_member) >= (
        CASE
            WHEN date(month_createdAt) < date '2021-03-01' THEN 700000
            ELSE 350000
        END
    )
) t3
```

In the end you check also for the `min_month` and `min_year`, then you group based on these attributes and `COUNT` how many members in each group.

```
SELECT min_year, min_month, COUNT(users_id)
FROM t1
WHERE users_id IN (...) AND     
    (((min_year < 2021 OR min_month < 3) AND t1.sum_price >= 700000) OR 
    ((min_year = 2021 AND min_month = 3) AND t1.sum_price >= 350000))
GROUP BY min_year, min_month
```

I have not immediately understood what your goal is and I am not sure I get it now, that is why I changed this query a few times by now so you might be able to simplify it.

Comment: This is right only for march, but when i change it in ```WHERE DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') = '202103'``` into ```WHERE DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') = '202102'``` (when i want to find out ```star member``` in month february, then its still same with march, instead its only user_id 16 which count_user_id is ```1```

Comment: @18818181881 Thanks, try it now. However, if it is not what you want, please update your question with some example so that we can better understand your problem

Comment: thankyou for the answer, i want to make a query, to find out star member, on this case in march, you have done right, but lets say i want to find out on ```april 2021```, then i thought it will as simple as change in ```WHERE DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') =``` just like my first query, when i want to find out another month, then i'll just change in  ```HAVING SUM(year_and_month = 'year_and_month'```